# How to Self-Study Mathematical Methods?

Tags: self-learning, education, book-recommendation

**Edit:**

Ok, user [Chinny84](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185956/self-study-math-for-computer-science-and-learning-to-read-papers#comment2415036_1185956) made comment that truly helps narrow the focus of my question. Basically, I'm asking for a self-study course of Mathematical Methods.

Thanks to his recommendation I identified a book that is very close to the answer:

Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences by Mary L. Boas

Supposedly, the book covers most of the Math a person needs to learn in order to understand the simulations I presented.

Does this book suit my needs?

---

Hello,

I have always been interested on the idea to study Math at an Undergraduate level to be able to implement simulations like the followings:

**Finite Difference Simulation of the Wave Equation**

[image]

**Heat Equation in Two Dimensions**

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Heat_eqn.gif]

Besides my precollege experience in Math, I have only been able to do very simple simulations due to my lack of knowledge of Advanced Math. Every time I ask about the inner workings of the simulations I get redirected to papers that look like foreign language to me and, unfortunately, I depend on easy-to-read tutorials to understand them, and while I have found [very helpful explanations](http://www.karlsims.com/rd.html)  I'm more interested in reaching the solution myself.

I checked some of the questions related to book recommendations for self-study and while they are very helpful I'm interested in **learning by example** (There is a book called: "Accelerated C++ Practical Programming by Example" that fits very well my study habits)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site! What specifically is your question?

Comment: @HBeel, how to read computer science papers and book recommendations/courses (self study) that cover the topics I posted, with focus on observational training (learning by example)

Comment: Have a look at: [Theoretical CS and Math - self-study recommendations](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7334).

Comment: @JoseArnaldoDris, I have already checked that! :) I'm more interested in the math than in the algorithms, thanks though.

Comment: To be honest, those simulations are to solve either engineering or physics problems, and the maths is the model behind them. So do you want to purely understand the maths? Or implement the models? If it's the former then for implementing models you probably just need introduction to mathematical methods for engineers/physics but if you want to understand beyond that then most of those topics would be covered in individual texts with only a couple being shared in the same binding. But an interesting question is hidden in your post :) +1

Comment: @Chinny84 _"So do you want to purely understand the maths? Or implement the models?"_ Both, but understanding the math is more important for me. _"introduction to mathematical methods"_ So, numerical methods? There are still some prerequisites that I need complete in order to study it.

Comment: The introduction to mathematical methods is just a general name for textbooks that discusses and shows problems/excerises of mathematical methods such as pdes, linear algebra and series etc etc for physicists/engineers. These books tend to cover most of the topics if not all of the ones you mentioned above.

Comment: Though, Remember, that the intro texts do not deep dive into the mathematic theorems that lead to the very important results that are applied..so look at Mary boas text (I used it quite a lot when the mathematics textbooks got too hairy ;). But depending on your level of mathematics, I suggest that as a good point, and then take it from there.

Comment: @Chinny84, You hit the nail on the head, I think is time to rewrite the question, and direct the focus to Mathematical Methods, which is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The simulations you showed should be explained in textbooks about numerically solving PDEs, so there's no need to worry about reading papers at this point.  The heat equation example could be implemented in like half a page of Matlab using a simple finite difference method.

Comment: If you are prepared to absorb some original and uncommon stuff, there is my website on [Unified Numerical Analysis](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/sunall/index.htm).

Answer (score 2):

The courses and book you mentions above is for basic engineering, physics problems. I think in your case, it's more about the applications than theorem. But, here are some books that you should check out and it combines a lot of pure math:

Single and Multi Variable Calculus: Calculus, 7ed by James Stewared

Fourier Transform and Analysis:  A First Course in Wavelets with Fourier Analysis by Albert Boggess and Francis J. Narcowich (You should have basic knowledge about linear algebra and some Differential Equation in order to understand Fourier Transform)

Linear Algebra: Linear Algebra and its Application by Gilber Strang. More Advance we have, Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler

Differential Equation: Ordinary Differential Equation by Morris Tenenbau and Harry Pollard. More advance: Introduction to Ordinary Differential Equation by Agarwal, or even deeper: Ordinary Differential Equations by  Edward L. Ince

Partial Differential Equation: Partial Differential Equation for Scientists and Engineer by Stanley. More advance: Partial Differential Equation by Strauss (he talks about Fourier Transform in this book too), or Partial Differential Equation by Lawrence C. Evans (I love this book because it's very detail)

About reading papers,let says a paper in Mathematics about PDE; it requires that your knowledge must be very deep in PDE in order to understand that paper, not just reading some basic books.

Comment: Thanks for answering!, I got a couple of questions: 1) "_The courses and book you mentions above"_ What books? 2)Do the books you mentioned are at an undergraduate level (for the unfamiliar)? 3) _"Partial Differential Equation"_ I read that the books you mentioned are a little advanced, thats why I selected Haberman's book for PDE, is that OK?

Comment: 1) My roommate is Physics major, and he has several books about Mathematics for Physics, but, I forgot. I need to check them again. 2)The first book in each topic that I mentioned is always coming with a lot of simple examples,I think you can self study with those books, except the book about Fourier Analysis, it's little bit more advance. But, in the case you want to know more theory, you can go to next book. 3) unfortunately, I haven't read that book, but "Partial Differential Equation for Scientists and Engineer by Stanley" has step by step example, and you can take a look at that.